# When I change the a JQuery datepicker's DOM place it does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I have a button for showing JQuery datepicker (version: 1.8.20).

After running this code:

```
if (scope===document){
  var a=$("input.datepicker");
  $('#header').append(a);
}
```

This error appear:

```
jquery-ui-1.8.20.custom.min.js:65 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined
    at Datepicker._showDatepicker (jquery-ui-1.8.20.custom.min.js:65)
    at jquery-ui-1.8.20.custom.min.js:65
    at Function.each (jquery-1.7.2.min.js:2)
    at init.each (jquery-1.7.2.min.js:2)
    at init.$.fn.datepicker (jquery-ui-1.8.20.custom.min.js:65)
    at showDatePicker (default.js:270)
    at HTMLInputElement.<anonymous> (default.js:249)
    at HTMLInputElement.dispatch (jquery-1.7.2.min.js:3)
    at HTMLInputElement.i (jquery-1.7.2.min.js:3)
```

Comment: There is a problem in your remaining code where you are using `toLowerCase`

Comment: @MilanChheda that is not how to interpret that error. Look at the stack trace closer

Comment: `toLowerCase` is in Jquery library code of datepicker. here: `jquery-ui-1.8.20.custom.min.js`

Comment: Snippet shown tells us next to nothing. Provide a [mcve]

Comment: @charlietfl - Are you pointing to `showDatePicker (default.js:270)`?

Comment: I should fix an web applications bugs.
I remove this line 

`$(this).click(function () {
 $(this).datepicker('show');
});`
The problem solved but there is also other problem:
After opening the menu for select a date if I click on scroll the datepicker become disapear (It's ok) but I reclick on the button for choosing other date the datepicker don't come.
In this situation I should click anywhere on HTML page.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all.

I upgrade the JQuery Version and the problem solved.

I have to upgrade all the code because of the deprecated methods.